# Making inherited getters to return mock objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, mockito

I want the inherited getters in class A to return Mock of MyObject. How can I do that without directly stubbing getMyObject() method in A (i.e. via using some MockBase class) ?

```
     public class Base {
         @Autowired
         private MyObject obj;
         public MyObject getMyObject(){
            return obj;
         }
     }


    public class A extends Base {
     @Autowired
     private SomeObject xyz; 

     public void myMethod(){
       MyObject  obj = getMyObject();
       //do something here
      }

    }

  public void MockBase {
      @Mock
      protected MyObject obj;

      public MyObject getMyObject(){
            return obj;
      }
  }

  public class ATest extends MockBase  {
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private SomeObject xyz;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    } 

    public void MyMethod_SomeCondition_ExpectedResult{
       a.myMethod();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the issue there ? It's working as expected, maybe you ar using an older version of Mockito. For example with version 1.9.5 :

Heres's the parent of the class you want to test :

```
public class Base {
    private BaseObjectDependency base_object_dependency;

    public BaseObjectDependency getBase_object_dependency() {
        return base_object_dependency;
    }
}
```

Here's the class you want to test :

```
public class Child extends Base {
    private ChildObjectDependency child_object_dependency;

    public void myMethod() {
        BaseObjectDependency obj = getBase_object_dependency();
        //do something here
    }

    public ChildObjectDependency getChild_object_dependency() {
        return child_object_dependency;
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies :

```
public class BaseObjectDependency { }

public class ChildObjectDependency { }
```

Now here's the parent class of the test :

```
import org.mockito.Mock;

public class MockBase {
    @Mock protected BaseObjectDependency base_test_dependency_mock;
}
```

And finally the test :

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class ChildTest extends MockBase {
    @InjectMocks private Child child;

    @Mock private ChildObjectDependency child_test_dependency_mock;


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void check_that_mocks_are_correctly_injected() {
        assertNotNull(child.getBase_object_dependency());
        assertEquals(base_test_dependency_mock, child.getBase_object_dependency());

        assertNotNull(child.getChild_object_dependency());
        assertEquals(child_test_dependency_mock, child.getChild_object_dependency());
    }
}
```

You'll see that nowhere I am stubbing `getBase_object_dependency()`.